# Parse Facebook feed datetime in python?

Tags: python, django, datetime, facebook, feedparser

1. I am reading a Facebook updates feed using the python library 'feedparser'.
2. I loop through the collection of entries in my Django templates, and display the results.
3. The updated field is returned in a big long string, of some format I am unfamiliar with.

   Tue, 01 Dec 2009 23:55:52 +0000

How can I...

**A) Use a Django filter to clean the date time in the for loop on the template.**

...or...

**B) Parse the date and format the updated date in the view, esentially cleaning the date in the collection of entries before it is iterated over in the view.**

*NOTE: I have tried both approaches. Django's date filter does't recognize it, and the iso8601 library I tried to parse the string didn't either.*

Anybody have any experience with this? Thanks for your help!

**UPDATE:**

Using the updated_parsed value from feedparser in a Django template didn't work so well. But a Django snippet of a filter for this very thing already exists!**

**Django Snippet:** http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1595/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `entries[i].updated_parsed` instead of `entries[i].updated`, and `feedparser` will return a parsed 9-tuple for you. ([Documentation](http://feedparser.org/docs/date-parsing.html))

Then build a `datetime` object and pass it to Django or format to a string by yourself.

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225274/parsing-different-date-formats-from-feedparser-in-python).

Comment: I like your solution but passing the tuple into Django's filter doesn't seem to work. I just get blank when I use the date filter. Maybe there's a better way to format it.

Comment: I updated the post with the link to the Django filter for feedparser dates.

Answer (score 2):

*This worked but wasn't what my final solution ended up becoming.*

This solution iterates over the feed entries collection I get back from Facebook. I then parse the datetime and set the updated property to that new datetime. (Also, ignoring the +0000)

```
for entry in feed.entries:
        entry.updated = datetime.strptime(entry.updated, "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S +0000")
```

The entries collection is returned to the template which I can now use the Django 'date' filter to format the date.

Comment: This worked fine, but the accepted solution leverages the feedparser framework which is +1 better.